# Capturing data between header rows based on a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having difficulty looping through rows of data between header rows to extract information and then sum the data from a few of the columns below the header row until it reaches the next header row. I am by no means a VBA expert vut Im trying to figure this out on my own and I've stripped down the code to just the basics trying to get this portion to work properly. I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach to this, but I'm importing the data from the "Raw Data" worksheet into an array ("rdA", currently working fine), then trying to put the header data I need into one temporary array ("rdB", works for the first line, then gives an "Out of Range error) and information from the data rows below it into another temporary array ("rdC") so that I can try to sum data and add the sums to the first temporary array.

The header row always starts with [StartIspn] and I need to extract specific data from the header row (time stamp, user ID, and side). I then need to sum data from a few columns of the rows below, but only for the rows that contain "A13" in column E. The sample image below shows what the raw data looks like. The top gray header row is just in this example to define the columns of data between the headers. My thoughts are that this needs to be loops inside of loops to gather and sum the necessary data, but I'm currently getting stuck trying to get the data to go into the temp arrays. My end goal is to create an array that contains Wafer S/N (column B of rows between headers), Time Stamp, User ID, Wafer Side (all from each header row), and the sum of column F, sum of column H, Min of column I and Max of column J for all rows containing "A13" in column 6 between header rows.

If I can at least get some guidance as to whether or not the approach I'm using is wrong, and how to get past the out of range error when trying to add data to the temporary arrays, I'd be grateful.

Here's what I have so far:

```
' Define that arrays start with index 1 instead of 0
Option Base 1

' Define that variables must be defined manually and will never be defined automatically
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Report()

    ' Define variable names and types
    Dim chkAnn  As String   ' Check column 5 for inspection type (A13)
    Dim chkHdr  As String   ' Check column 2 for StartIspn or S/N
    Dim fmTot   As String   ' Sum the total FM area per inspection
    Dim fmNum   As Long     ' Sum the total number of FM particles per inspection
    Dim fmMin   As Long     ' Find the min FM particle size per inspection
    Dim fmMax   As Long     ' Find the max FM particle size per inspection
    Dim h       As Long     ' Row count for FM data
    Dim i       As Long     ' Row count of number of rows being processed
    Dim idCol   As String   ' Time stamp from raw data header line
    Dim idPos   As Long     ' Position of time stamp in raw data header cell
    Dim idVal   As String   ' Time stamp from ecah inspection
    Dim j       As Long     ' Row count for report data array
    Dim k       As Long     ' Row count for debug print
    Dim lRow    As Long     ' Count of number of rows in Raw Data
    Dim m       As Long     ' Row count for debug print
    Dim tsCol   As String   ' Time stamp from raw data header line
    Dim tsPos   As Long     ' Position of time stamp in raw data header cell
    Dim tsVal   As String   ' Time stamp from ecah inspection
    Dim rdA()   As Variant  ' Array of imported Raw Data for parsing
    Dim rdB()   As Variant  ' Array of processed data for report output
    Dim rdC()   As Variant  ' Temp array of FM totals
    Dim wfrSN   As String   ' Wafer serial number from line below header row
    Dim wsCol   As String   ' Time stamp from raw data header line
    Dim wsPos   As Long     ' Position of time stamp in raw data header cell
    Dim wsVal   As String   ' Time stamp from ecah inspection

    ' Clear all arrays and variables in case report is run again
    Erase rdA
    ReDim rdA(1, 1)
    Erase rdB
    ReDim rdB(1, 1)
    h = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    ' Find number of populated rows in Raw Data
    lRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Create array of data from "Raw Data" worksheet
    rdA = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Q1").Resize(lRow, 17).Value2

    ' PER INSPECTION GROUP
    ' Check each line of raw data and extract required info from header row
    j = 1
    For i = LBound(rdA, 1) To UBound(rdA, 1)
        chkHdr = rdA(i, 2)
        chkAnn = rdA(i, 5)
        Const Hdr = "[StartIspn]"

        ' Check row for [StartIspn] in rdA Col 2
        If InStr(1, chkHdr, Hdr, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

            ' Collect Wafer Serial Number from next row and add to report array
            wfrSN = rdA(i + 1, 2)
            rdB(j, 1) = wfrSN

            ' Collect Time Stamp of inspections and add to report array
            tsCol = rdA(i, 3)
            tsPos = InStrRev(tsCol, "=")
            tsVal = Mid$(tsCol, tsPos + 1)
            rdB(j, 2) = tsVal

            ' Collect User ID and add to report array
            idCol = rdA(i, 4)
            idPos = InStrRev(idCol, "=")
            idVal = Mid$(idCol, idPos + 1)
            rdB(j, 3) = idVal

            ' Collect Wafer Side and add to report array
            wsCol = rdA(i, 6)
            wsPos = InStrRev(wsCol, "=")
            wsVal = Mid$(wsCol, wsPos + 1)
                If wsVal = "T" Then
                   wsVal = "Front"
                ElseIf wsVal = "B" Then
                       wsVal = "Back"
                End If
            rdB(j, 4) = wsVal

            ' Resize the report array for the next data set
            If j > 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve rdB(j - 1)
            End If

            ' Advance to next line in report array (rdB)
            j = j + 1

        Else
        For h = LBound(rdA, 1) To UBound(rdA, 1)
        chkAnn = rdA(h, 5)
        Const Ann = "A13"

            If InStr(1, chkAnn, Ann, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

            'Collect Wafer Serial Number
            wfrSN = rdA(i, 2)
            rdC(h, 1) = wfrSN

            ' Collect FM Total
            fmTot = rdA(i, 6)
            rdC(h, 2) = fmTot

            ' Collect # of FM Particles
            fmNum = rdA(i, 8)
            rdC(h, 3) = fmNum

            ' Collect Min Particle Size
            fmMin = rdA(i, 9)
            rdC(h, 4) = fmMin

            ' Collect Max Particle Size
            fmMax = rdA(i, 10)
            rdC(h, 5) = fmMax

            ' Advance to next line in temp array (rdC)
            h = h + 1

            End If

        Next h

     Next i

    For k = LBound(rdB, 1) To UBound(rdB, 1)
        Debug.Print rdB(k, 1) & ", " & _
                    rdB(k, 2) & ", " & _
                    rdB(k, 3) & ", " & _
                    rdB(k, 4)
    Next k

    For m = LBound(rdC, 1) To UBound(rdC, 1)
        Debug.Print rdC(m, 1) & ", " & _
                    rdC(m, 2) & ", " & _
                    rdC(m, 3) & ", " & _
                    rdC(m, 4) & ", " & _
                    rdC(m, 5)
    Next m

End Sub
```

[image: Sample Raw Data]

[image: Sample Output From Data]

Updated and working Code:

```
Sub Create_Report()
    Dim vDB, vResult(), vSum1(), vSum2(), vMin(), vMax()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim s As String, i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    Dim k As Integer

    Const Hdr = "[StartIspn]"
    Const Ann = "A13"

    Set Ws = Sheets("Raw Data")
    Set wsResult = Sheets("AOI Inspection Summary")

    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)

    For i = 1 To r
        If InStr(vDB(i, 2), Hdr) Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To 9, 1 To n)
            vResult(1, n) = n
            vResult(2, n) = vDB(i + 1, 2)
            vResult(3, n) = Replace(vDB(i, 3), "Time=", "")
            vResult(4, n) = Replace(vDB(i, 4), "User=", "")
            s = Replace(vDB(i, 6), "Side=", "")
            If s = "T" Then
                vResult(5, n) = "Front"
            Else
                vResult(5, n) = "Back"
            End If
            If k > 0 Then
                vResult(6, n - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vSum1)
                vResult(7, n - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vSum2)
                vResult(8, n - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Min(vMin)
                vResult(9, n - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Max(vMax)
                k = 0
            End If
        Else
            If InStr(vDB(i, 5), Ann) Then
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve vSum1(1 To k)
            ReDim Preserve vSum2(1 To k)
            ReDim Preserve vMin(1 To k)
            ReDim Preserve vMax(1 To k)
            vSum1(k) = vDB(i, 6)
            vSum2(k) = vDB(i, 8)
            vMin(k) = vDB(i, 9)
            vMax(k) = vDB(i, 10)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    vResult(6, n) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vSum1)
    vResult(7, n) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vSum2)
    vResult(8, n) = WorksheetFunction.Min(vMin)
    vResult(9, n) = WorksheetFunction.Max(vMax)

    With wsResult 'array Result write on sheet
        .Range("b21").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).ClearContents
        .Range("b23").Resize(n, 9) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vResult)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `ReDim Preserve rdB(j - 1)` when using `Preserve` you can only change the last dimension of a multi-dimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vResult(), vSum(), vMin(), vMax()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, wsResult As Worksheet
    Dim s As String, i As Long, n As Long, r As Long
    Dim k As Integer

    Const Hdr = "[StartIspn]"

    Set Ws = Sheets("Raw Data")
    Set wsResult = Sheets("AOI Inspection Summary")

    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)

    For i = 2 To r '<~~ if your Raw data row 1 data is Row#, Watar S/n.... i start 2 else 1
        If InStr(vDB(i, 2), Hdr) Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To 9, 1 To n)
            vResult(1, n) = n
            vResult(2, n) = vDB(i + 1, 2)
            vResult(3, n) = Replace(vDB(i, 3), "Time=", "")   'time
            vResult(4, n) = Replace(vDB(i, 4), "User=", "")   'Positon
            s = Replace(vDB(i, 6), "Sided=", "")
            If s = "T" Then
                vResult(5, n) = "Front"
            Else
                vResult(5, n) = "Back"
            End If
            If k > 0 Then
                vResult(6, n - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vSum)
                vResult(7, n - 1) = 37 '<~~ what mean # of particle
                vResult(8, n - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Min(vMin)
                vResult(9, n - 1) = WorksheetFunction.Max(vMax)
                k = 0
            End If
        Else
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve vSum(1 To k)
            ReDim Preserve vMin(1 To k)
            ReDim Preserve vMax(1 To k)
            vSum(k) = vDB(i, 6)
            vMin(k) = vDB(i, 9)
            vMax(k) = vDB(i, 10)
        End If
    Next i
    vResult(6, n) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(vSum)
    vResult(7, n) = 37 '<~~ what mean # of particle
    vResult(8, n) = WorksheetFunction.Min(vMin)
    vResult(9, n) = WorksheetFunction.Max(vMax)

    With wsResult 'array Result write on sheet
        .Range("b21").CurrentRegion.Offset(2).ClearContents
        .Range("b23").Resize(n, 9) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vResult)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I had to do a few modifications to the code to get it working properly, but your example definitely taught me a new method for working with virtual data arrays and showed me an entirely different and more efficient approach on this. Thank you so much for your guidance and assistance! I posted the updated the code above with modifications to only sum data in rows containing A13, adding vSum2 to sum the # of particles, and correcting a column error and spelling error for Side= "Front" or "Back". It all seems to be working correctly now. Thanks again!